# docker run -v & .dockerignore trying to ignore folder

Tags: docker

I have a sub folder `MyFolder` that I add/is added with `docker run -v pwd:imagefolder`.

```
project
- MyFolder/WithSomeFiles
- Dockerfile
```

So in `project`  folder I do `docker run -v (pwd):project` this is adding the current folder incl. MyFolder.

Is it possible to ignore `MyFolder` when using `docker run -v`?

I have tried to add the folder name to `.dockerignore`, but it looks like that is only for Dockerfile.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry I don't understand what you mean? Clearly I did not discribe the problem good enough.

Comment: Yes, add a bit more details.

Comment: Thanks How about now, is it more clear?

Comment: Yep, this is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker run -v` causes a host directory to be mounted into a container's filesystem as-is.  There's no "copying" and no "ignore" facility.  (It doesn't cost extra time or space to have the unwanted directory, but you also can't hide it.)

If this is a problem, you might need to restructure your application to keep its data somewhere other than its own source tree.  If you're bind-mounting your application's code into a container you should also consider setting up a `docker build` pipeline and *not* bind-mounting your code, which can simplify some complicated bind-mount setups.